# Link2SD cannot mount second partition after re-flashing CM 11

Tags: link2sd

After re-flashing a version of CM 11 I'd been using for a while with no problems on my Samsung Galaxy S Blaze 4G, I can't get Link2SD to mount the second partition. I'd been using Link2SD with no issues at all before.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Link2SD and tried Ext2 and Ext3 just to be sure (the partition formatted Ext4) but I get this error every time I try to mount the card in Link2SD:

"Mount Script Error - mount script cannot be created. Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(0)"

I don't know what this means, or what to try next. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - there was a problem with the file itself. The developer sent me a beta APK file that fixed it immediately.